# Updated Gradle Now compileGoovy failing with "unable to resolve class"

Tags: gradle, grails, groovy

This is some of the errors.  The XXXX represents personal or confidential information.

```
/Users/XXXXXXX/Documents/XXXX/XXXX/internal-tools/grails-app/utils/com/XXXXXX/utils/DomainUtils.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class com.XXXXXX.util.DateHelper
 @ line 3, column 1.
   import com.XXXXXXX.util.DateHelper
   ^

/Users/XXXXXXX/Documents/XXXX/XXXXX/internal-tools/grails-app/utils/com/XXXXXXXX/utils/TemporalUtil.groovy: 4: unable to resolve class com.XXXXXXX.util.DateHelper
 @ line 4, column 1.
   import com.XXXXXXX.util.DateHelper
   ^

/Users/XXXXXX/Documents/XXXX/XXXX/internal-tools/grails-app/utils/com/XXXXX/utils/TemporalUtil.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class com.XXXXXXX.data.JodaTemporal
 @ line 3, column 1.
   import com.XXXXXXX.data.JodaTemporal
   ^

851 errors

org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':internal-tools:compileGroovy'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfoExecutor.execute(LocalTaskInfoExecutor.java:42)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:277)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:135)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:200)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeWithWork(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:191)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ApiGroovyCompiler.execute(ApiGroovyCompiler.java:184)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ApiGroovyCompiler.execute(ApiGroovyCompiler.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.GroovyCompilerFactory$DaemonSideCompiler.execute(GroovyCompilerFactory.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.GroovyCompilerFactory$DaemonSideCompiler.execute(GroovyCompilerFactory.java:65)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.AbstractDaemonCompiler$CompilerCallable.call(AbstractDaemonCompiler.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.AbstractDaemonCompiler$CompilerCallable.call(AbstractDaemonCompiler.java:76)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:42)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.WorkerDaemonServer.execute(WorkerDaemonServer.java:46)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.WorkerDaemonServer.execute(WorkerDaemonServer.java:30)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.request.WorkerAction.run(WorkerAction.java:101)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:155)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:137)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
        ... 3 more
```

This is the build.gradle

```
//
// Basic project info
//
description = 'Root Project Build'

ext {
    //
    // Boilerplate gradle CM support
    //
    buildMajorVersion = 195
    isWindows = org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem.current().windows
}

// Make library versions are available in all projects
allprojects {
    ext {
        springVersion = '4.1.4.RELEASE'

        // Scala versions
        scalaVersion = '2.12.3'
        scalaBinaryVersion = scalaVersion.tokenize('.').take(2).join('.')
    }
}

apply from: 'cm.gradle'
apply from: 'config.gradle'
apply from: 'db.gradle'
apply from: 'test.gradle'


subprojects {
    //
    // project specific dependencies
    //
    def springVersion = ext.springVersion

    //
    // Grails is VERY picky about spring version, so we will
    // hold all versions to that defined above regardless of
    // transitive dependencies
    //
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'org.springframework' && details.requested.name != 'springloaded') {
                    details.useVersion springVersion
                }
            }
        }
    }


    //
    // Locations for common configuration
    //
    ext {
        springJndiFile = "$rootDir/dev/jndi/data-source.xml"
    }

    configurations.all {
        // already provided by the JVM, Grails complains if classes show up twice in the classpath
        exclude group: 'log4j', module: 'log4j'
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
        exclude group: 'commons-logging'
    }

    //
    // Ensure files are compiled with the proper encoding
    //
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.encoding = "UTF-8"
    }

    tasks.withType(ScalaCompile) {
        options.encoding = "UTF-8"
    }

    afterEvaluate {
        if (plugins.hasPlugin('java')) {
            dependencies {
                // Logback (http://logback.qos.ch/)
                runtime 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3'

                // SLF4J (http://www.slf4j.org/)
                compile 'org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:1.7.7' // and the log4j bridge
                runtime 'org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.2' // and the commons-logging bridge

                runtime "p6spy:p6spy:1.3"

                // Spring support (http://www.springsource.org/)
                compile "org.springframework:spring-core:${springVersion}"
                compile "org.springframework:spring-web:${springVersion}"
                compile "org.springframework:spring-webmvc:${springVersion}"
                compile "org.springframework:spring-jdbc:${springVersion}"
                compile "org.springframework:spring-context-support:${springVersion}"
                compile "org.springframework:spring-orm:${springVersion}"
                compile "org.springframework:spring-aspects:${springVersion}"
                testCompile "org.springframework:spring-test:${springVersion}"

                // JPA2 annotations to satisfy a dependency of the spring-aspects
                compile 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final'

                // Apache Commons (http://commons.apache.org/)
                compile 'commons-cli:commons-cli:1.2'
                compile 'commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1'
                compile 'commons-configuration:commons-configuration:1.6'
                compile 'commons-io:commons-io:1.4'
                compile 'commons-validator:commons-validator:1.6'

                // Database connection pooling (https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP)
                compile 'com.zaxxer:HikariCP:2.3.7'

                // Joda Time (http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)
                compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.6'

                // Guava (https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)
                compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'

                // Persistent Collections (http://code.google.com/p/pcollections/)
                compile 'org.pcollections:pcollections:2.1.2'

                // For removing HTML from error responses
                compile "org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.2"

                // Tuples for Java (http://www.javatuples.org)
                compile 'org.javatuples:javatuples:1.2'

                // Jackson XML (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)
                compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.5.0'
                compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.5.0'
                compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.5.0'

                // Jackson XML data binding for Joda Time (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-joda)
                compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:2.5.0'

                // Jackson Java 8 types (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jdk8)
                compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.5.0'

                compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.11'
            }

            //
            // Enable lint compilation for compile output
            //
            tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
                options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked"
                // Uncomment to display deprecated classes and usage
                // options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation"
            }

            //
            // Add source jars to the build
            //
            task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
                classifier = 'sources'
                from sourceSets.main.allSource
            }

            artifacts {
                archives sourcesJar
            }
        }
    }
}


//
// Include the IDE after the block defining the 'provided' configuration
// since that configuration is used for IntelliJ support.
//
apply from: 'ide.gradle'
// So IntelliJ doesn't complain about the output dirs in non-Java projects
idea.module {
    outputDir = file("$buildDir/classes/main")
    testOutputDir = file("$buildDir/classes/test")
}


task showStatus {
    doFirst {
        println "Current buildinfo properties: " + buildvcs.getInfo().toString()
    }
}
uploadArchives.dependsOn(showStatus)

//
// Do some ordering for clean task for baseline subprojects
//
clean.dependsOn("business-logic:clean")


//
// build script dependency settings
//
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/" }
        maven { url "http://kercheval.org/mvn-repo/releases/" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.kercheval:GradleCMPlugin:1.+'
        classpath 'com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.+' // Force a newer version for the CM plugin to fix Github auth issues
        classpath 'org.gradle.api.plugins:gradle-nexus-plugin:0.2'
    }
}
```

This is the internal-tools.gradle

```
description = 'Internal Tools'

ext {
    grailsVersion = "3.3.10"
}

apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin: "war"
//apply plugin: 'groovy' //Did not help

grails {
    grailsVersion = "3.3.10"
    // springLoadedVersion = '1.2.4.RELEASE'
}

configurations.all {
    // already provided by the JVM, Grails complains if classes show up twice in the classpath
    exclude group: 'xml-apis', module: 'xml-apis'

    exclude module: 'grails-plugin-log4j'

    //provided servlet container
    exclude group: 'javax.el', module: 'el-api'
    exclude group: 'org.glassfish.web', module: 'el-impl'
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':business-logic')
    // test(project(path: ':business-logic', configuration: 'testArtifacts'))

    def slf4jVersion = '1.7.2'
    compile "org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:${slf4jVersion}"
    compile "org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:${slf4jVersion}"
    compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:${slf4jVersion}"


    // We force a newer version of Ant to work around a bug in the Oracle JRE.  This can be removed when Grails upgrades Ant
    // See Ant 'Bug 54641' for more details
    runtime "org.apache.ant:ant:1.9.2"
    runtime "org.apache.ant:ant-junit:1.9.2"

  //  compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.15' //Did not help

    // Grails
    runtime "org.grails:grails-dependencies:$grailsVersion"

    // Grails plugins
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:6.+"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:tomcat:7.0.+"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:export:1.6"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:webflow:2.1.0"
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:logback:0.3.1'
    runtime "org.grails:grails-plugin-validation:$grailsVersion"

    // test "org.grails:grails-test:$grailsVersion"
    // test "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing:$grailsVersion"
    // test 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.1'
    // test 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.8.0'
    // test 'nekohtml:nekohtml:1.9.6.2'

    // bootstrap 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3'
}

test {
    doFirst {
        tasks.getByPath(':dbTestCreate').ext.testDatabase.create()
    }

    dependsOn(':configProperties')
    jvmArgs '-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m'
    systemProperty 'XXXXX.conf.file', "$configOutputDir/XXXXX_test.properties"
    String protocol = "file:"
    systemProperty 'logback.configurationFile', protocol + new File(rootProject.projectDir,"dev/log/logback.xml").getAbsolutePath()
}

bootRun {
    dependsOn(':configProperties', ':dbValidate')
    jvmArgs '-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m'
    systemProperty 'XXXXX.conf.file', "$configOutputDir/XXXXX_dev.properties"
    String protocol = "file:"
    systemProperty 'logback.configurationFile', protocol + new File(rootProject.projectDir,"dev/log/logback.xml").getAbsolutePath()
}

war {
    String protocol = "file:"
    // systemProperty 'logback.configurationFile', protocol + new File(rootProject.projectDir,"dev/log/logback.xml").getAbsolutePath()
}

// We re-package the war so it will include the extra GradleCM meta-info.
// We use a zip task rather than a war task because the war task adds extra files such as a second web.xml
task reWar(type: Zip, dependsOn: ['war']) {
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/libs")
    extension = 'war'
    // HACK: the input needs to be wrapped in a closure so it is evaluated lazily. This is because the 'war' task output
    // file changes once the version is set
    from { zipTree(war.archiveName) }

    //
    // Build info file
    //
    from (rootProject.buildinfo.filedir) {
        include rootProject.buildinfo.filename
        into 'META-INF'
    }
}

artifacts {
    archives reWar
}

// Ensure tests are run for uploadArchives
uploadArchives.dependsOn('check')

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/" }
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/jfrog/jfrog-jars/" }
        maven { url "https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs-releases-local/" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/" }
        maven { url "https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:3.+"
        classpath "com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.+"
        classpath "org.gradle:gradle-tooling-api:5.+"
        classpath "org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.+"
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.  This happened when we went from gradle 2.2 to gradle 4.10.2.  I'm not sure if I need to upgrade groovy, or grails, or both.  If I should post our other .gradle files I can but the other ones are building fine so I did not include them.

I tried adding the apply groovy plugin but that didn't help.  I also added the compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.11' dependency and that did not help either.  Has anyone ran into this problem when they upgraded gradle and have groovy/grails in their project?
This built fine with gradle 2.2.  I really don't want to upgrade to a higher version than gradle 4.10.2 and I don't want to go below gradle 3.X, but I'm fine changing the version to something in between if that will help.  I did try some other versions but that did not help either.

Comment: I think that grails 3.x is "qualified" to use Gradle 3.x only, because of its own gradle-plugins

Comment: What version of grails is compatible with gradle 4.10.2?

Comment: grails 3.x is based on Gradle 3.x, grails 4.0.1 -> `Gradle 5.1.1`